# What is raid-ac protocol on port 2012

Tags: xcode, osx-server

Yesterday I made OS X Server, on Mac Mini, for Xcode Continuous Integration.
Today, by scanning my local network, I see that this Mac Mini is having port 2012 open with this raid-ac.

I googled but can not find any info regarding this raid-ac.
I suppose that this raid-ac is used for this Xcode Continuous Integration feature.

Can somebody provide more info about it ?

Comment: It's the protocol linked to that port : ftp://www.ietf.org/iana/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt

Comment: Is there some explanation for not hard-core geeks ? :-)

Comment: @Rob by this I meant on the name of the protocol

Answer (score -1):

As far I know **RAID**, it's a way to store data across multiple disks (HDD) acting like one.

There are multiple standard levels of them as explained on [this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Standard_levels) (might be *geeky* as you say).

Based on that knowledge I would say the services works with redundancy in order to run smoothly. As you say yourself: Continuous Integration (as in, without interruption)

Please check source below:

> UDP port 2012 uses the Datagram Protocol [red. that's what UDP means], a communications protocol
>   for the Internet network layer, transport layer, and session layer.
>   This protocol when used over PORT 2012 makes possible the transmission
>   of a datagram message from one computer to an application running in
>   another computer. Like TCP (Transmission Control Protocol), UDP is
>   used with IP (the Internet Protocol) but unlike TCP on Port 2012, UDP
>   Port 2012 is connectionless and does not guarantee reliable
>   communication; it’s up to the application that received the message on
>   Port 2012 to process any errors and verify correct delivery.
>   [source](http://www.auditmypc.com/udp-port-2012.asp)

Comment: You're only making suppositions right ? References would be great to support your answer.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I was, until my edit looking for references or information. TBH, it's amazingly hard to find.

Comment: I am familiar with RAID, but I doubt that raid-ac have anything with RAID. I do not see the connection. Maybe this raid-ac is used for https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/ ?

Comment: @Rob The info and link you’ve added in your edit say nothing particular about port 2012 or raid-ac, just generalities about UDP.

Comment: +1. I also did an intensive research and find nothing but standard generated text like your edit. That's really strange.

Comment: I start to wonder if Area51 is involved @MatthieuRiegler ;)